# Creating a matrix from the coefficients of equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Given the equations

```
eqn1 = 5 x1 + 2 x2 + 3 x3 == 8
eqn2 = 4 x1 + 7 x2 + 9 x3 == 5
eqn3 = 6 x1 +   x2 + 9 x3 == 2
```

how do I extract the coefficients of `x1, x2, x3` to form a matrix?

I tried using `CoefficientArrays` but the output was given as a `SparseArray`.

Comment: `Normal` will convert a `SparseArray` into an ordinary matrix.

Answer (score 11):

Try  `Normal`

```
(Normal[CoefficientArrays[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}, {x1, x2, x3}]][[2]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am not fond of `Normal`

```
Coefficient[# /. Equal[e_, _] -> e, {x1, x2, x3}] & /@ {eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}
```

Shorter but not as clear:

```
Coefficient[First@#, {x1, x2, x3}] & /@ {eqn1, eqn2, eqn3}
```

Comment: Why the aversion to `Normal`?

Comment: @rcollyer Because the doc is not clear enough for my taste, and the phrase `When additional "data types" are introduced, Normal should be defined to convert them, when possible, to normal expressions.` is unique in all Mma documentation. Just a maniac personality symptom, I guess.